# Is there a keyboard shortcut to delete a branch in SourceTree [Mac]

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

Each time I want to delete a local branch, I must use my mouse to right-click it and select delete in the popup menu.

Is there a way to delete branches only using the keyboard?

My first assumption was that selecting a branch and pressing `Delete` or `Cmd + Delete` would remove the branch, but this does not do anything.